# How to access dynamic td value using jquery?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-3

First i want to access Amount value then use it as each loop , so dynamic field amount can be accessed.It would be great help from you if you could help me in same.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').each(function() {
    var totalAmt = 0;
    $(this).find('.total').each(function() {
      var myval = $(this).html();
      if (myval.length !== 0) {
        totalAmt += parseFloat(myval);
        alert(totalAmt);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="itm-detl">Project Selection</th>
      <th class="itm-detl">Item Details</th>
      <th class="qaunt-th width-100">Hours</th>
      <th class="qaunt-th width-100">Rate</th>
      <th class="qaunt-th width-100">Amount</th>
      <th class="blank-th"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="appended">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="project" name="project_selection[]" class="form-control select-item project ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Type or click to select Project" style="border: none;" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="itemdetails" name="item_details[]" class="form-control select-item description ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Type or click to select Item" style="border: none;" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="hour[]" class="form-control qaunt-td hour" placeholder="0.00" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="rate[]" class="form-control qaunt-td rate" placeholder="0.00" value="">
      </td>
      <td id="tamt" class="total-amt total">0.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Below code is dynamic one which appears when add new button is clicked.
<!-- Form ends here -->
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" style="display: none;">
  <tbody id="copyStructure">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="search" id="project" name="project_selection[]" class="form-control select-item project" placeholder="Type or click to select Project" style="border: none;" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" name="search" id="search-id" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="itemdetails" name="item_details[]" class="form-control select-item description" placeholder="Type or click to select Item" style="border: none;" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="hour[]" class="form-control qaunt-td hour" placeholder="0.00" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="rate[]" class="form-control qaunt-td rate" placeholder="0.00" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="total-amt total">0.00</td>
      <input type="hidden" name="amount[]">
      <td class="total-amt">
        <button type="button" class="remove btn btn-danger" name="removeBtn" id="removeBtn"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOYia.png)

I am unable to get value of class = '.total',  i have to add every total row only to create final total. checkout html also.

Comment: If you want to make Sum of All .total TD value then you need to move var totalAmt = 0; out of Each(Tr each) loop.

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA Still, it doesn't solve primary issue.Good you have noticed my mistake.

Comment: all other code is proper, Maybe It's(HTML) renders after your JS code execution, If it runs before then you need to execute JS function after the whole HTML renders

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA I got it around somehow, but it runs 2 times one with actual value and another withe empty value. I have used this code $(document).on('change', '.rate', function () {
  $(".finalt").each(function () {
   var sample = $(this).text();
    alert(sample);
   // if (sample != '') {
   //  sample += parseFloat(sample);
   // }
  });
 });

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by using code and mistake wasn't that big as it is clashing with variable names.

```
function calculateSubTotal() {
    var p_amt = 0;
    $(".total").each(function () {
        var sample1 = parseFloat($(this).text());
        if (sample1 != '') {
            p_amt += sample1;
        }
    });
    $('#subtotal').html(p_amt);
    $('#finaltotal').html(p_amt);
}
```